# Unable to change file name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, download

I use the Google Chrome browser, I am trying to change the name of the file that I download automatically.

```
public downloadImageJpeg(instanceUID: string, format: string): void {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.download = 'image.jpg';
  a.href =  'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/54789364/JPG-logo-highres.jpg';
  a.click();
}
```

This does not work, the file name is the name of the URL image: 'JPG-logo-highres.jpg' and not 'image.jpg'

Comment: The filename in your attribute does not always get respected. It could be ignored due to any of the reasons listed in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download As stated this can even vary depending on the browser you use. Also make sure you're actually using a browser that supports the attribute. For instance, Internet Explorer does not support this attribute in any version. Can you verify that none of those factors are influencing what is happening?

Comment: @ADyson
Thanks for your quick answer. I didn't understand what you said.. I need to try which parameters ?

Comment: read that documentation in the link I gave, particularly the bit in the yellow box for the "download" attribute. There are several factors which could cause the filename you gave in your attribute to be ignored: 1) browser support (list of browsers supporting the download attribute is shown at the bottom of the page), 2) whether it's a cross-origin request, 3) the Content-Disposition header sent by the server (and also which browser is receiving it). Again the link gives more detail on exactly what to check. So before you complain it doesn't work you need to check if those things are the cause